# Prove that: There is no Field for which $(\mathbb{F}^{2\times 2}, \cdot)$ is commutative.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory

Assuming it is about matrices in $\mathbb{R}$ and not taking edge cases into consideration.

Intuitively it is true that for $(\mathbb{F}^{2\times 2}, \cdot)$ commutative property doesn't hold true.

But I'm struggling to prove it with help of definition of Field. Help on it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, how would you prove it for $\mathbb{R}$?  Then you can see whether that proof works for a general field.

Comment: every field has $0$ and $1.$  Try pairs of matrices with those entries.

Comment: Do not use `x` for $\times$. Use `\times`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the matrices $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Their commutator $[A, B] = AB - BA = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which can only be $0$ if $0 = 1$. But that cannot happen in a field.